# Can IntelliJ generate DAO or Rest layer?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation, dao

I know that I can generate code based on my database schema using Hibernate, but that only creates models. Is there a way to generate base for DAO layer or Rest controllers? Most forum questions about this topic are years old and I couldn't find anything on IntelliJ web.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Telosys](http://telosys.org/) to generate a full rest backend (Controller, service and DAO layers) based on your database schema.

The advantage of using Telosys is that it provides a wide range of templates for most known languages and frameworks, and with few clicks you will have your full application ready.

Here is the wiki of how to use the command line interface: [Telosys-CLI](https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-cli/wiki)

In your case (Java), you can use this template to generate the rest controller layer:

- [Java web mvc spring](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-web-mvc-spring-T300-OLD)
- [Java web rest jaxrs](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-web-rest-jaxrs1-T300)

You will need then the commons service layer:

- [Java commons](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-commons-T300)
- [Java persistence commons](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-persistence-commons-T300)

And for your DAO layer you will be able to choose between:

- [Java persistence JDBC](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-persistence-jdbc-T300)
- [Java persistence JPA](https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3/java-persistence-jpa-T300)

Of course, those are templates based on Java language, but Python and Node.JS are available as well.

Comment: Thanks for an alternative! But do you really know that IntelliJ can't do this by itself?

Comment: As far as I know IntelliJ is not used for code generation. It can't generate a rest architecture. You might have plugins for intelliJ that can do the job, but you will be using an alternative.